# polymorphic association belongs to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a comments model which is a polymorphic association which is involved with Statuses and Photos. How can I create this polymorphic association to also belong to a User so that when a user creates a comment under statuses or photos it will also recieve the current_user id?

this is what I have as of now-

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

just to reiterate, how can I create a comment as a user but also have it under status or photo? it would need the user_id.

This is where I am having the trouble-
how should I set this up?

```
def create 
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comments_params) 
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky but I found a workaround. So in my CommentsController i did this:

```
def create 
    new_params = comments_params
    new_params[:user_id] = current_user.id
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(new_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

that placed the user_id which is what I needed.

Comment: this one is very old one, what i have answered. You can understand well from this www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_polymorphic.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :likable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to: user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses, :as => :likable
  has_many :photos, :as => :commentable 
  has_many :comments   


class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :likable, :dependent => :destroy  


class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: could you please explain?

Comment: if you say `@comment.likable` it should return status, `@comment.commentable` is should return photo, and `@user.photos`, `@user.statuses` should give `photos` and `statuses` for that user

Comment: you should be able to create `@comment = @status.comments.new(comments_params)` or `@comment = @photo.comments.new(comments_params)`